# How to use the navigation button inside a createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: navigation, react-native

I am using the createBottomTabNavigator and because of this I am not able to add the navigate function to a button. ie I would like to use the createBottomTabNavigator and also the createStackNavigator to create the routes

```
App.js

import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
...
render() {
 <AppNavigator />
}


AppNavigator.js
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
}));



MainTabNavigator.js
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import ColaboradorScreen from '../screens/ColaboradorScreen';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
           : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Links',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
```

};

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-options' : 'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};
```

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
      HomeStack,
      LinksStack,
      SettingsStack,
    });

See that I have the createBottomTabNavigator and it works perfectly however I have a screen called ColaboradorScreen where I want to open it in the click of a button.

On my homescreen screen I have how to render a button

```
<Button
title="Open C"
onPress={() => navigate('Colaborador')}
/>
```

How do I get my button to load the ContributorScreen?

Comment: Check this out [You can get the answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274781/showing-navigation-bottom-bar-in-screens-which-are-not-part-of-bottom-tabs-in-re)